# How to pass data to Platform.runLater

Tags: java, javafx, mutex

I need to change the title of my GUI window based on the socket data received in the socket receiver thread. I want to know is there a way to pass variables like `int`, `long` etc. to `Platform.runLater`, in order to avoid mutex locks just for accessing an `int` variable. This is a sample code:

```
// Receiver Socket thread
int opnMode = byteBuffer.getInt();

Platform.runLater(() -> { //GUI thread
    ((Stage) Fx.Pane.getScene().getWindow()).setTitle("Operation mode " + " (" + opnMode + ")");
});
```

In the above code I'm using the variable `opnMode` without using mutex as it is being accessed by two threads.

Comment: If `opnMode` is a local variable then you have nothing to worry about (at least based on the current code provided, which is not a [mre]).

Answer (score -2):

Your code should work just fine as it is because your int is effectively final.
Here is a discussion of this issue: https://www.baeldung.com/java-effectively-final